# Javascript - Can I change the volume of ALL audio elements at once?

Tags: javascript, audio, element, volume

I have a program with several Audio elements like this  `new Audio( url ).play()`
How can I change the volume of ALL Audio elements in my program at once.
I've seen other posts that show how to change volume for a single item like this...
`x=new Audio( url )  x.volume=0.2   x.play()`
but my sounds might have no variable or id applied to them or might have many different variables or ids applied to them. Can I change the volume of EVERYTHING in the program that is an Audio element?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put every `Audio` element into an array and create a function that will iterate over this array and set volume to each element:

```
const audios = [];
const audio1 = new Audio(url1);
audio1.play();
audios.push(audio1);

const audio2 = new Audio(url2);
audio2.play();
audios.push(audio2);   

function changeVolume(volume) {
  audios.forEach(audioElement => audioElement.volume = volume);
}

changeVolume(0.2);
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to combine 2 things like this `new Audio(url).play().volume=0.2;`

Comment: No, it is not possible to write it in that way because `.play()` method returns a Promise, not the Audio element

Comment: Please do not forget to upvote/mark answer as correct if iit resolved your issue. It will help other users.